# Blazor - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I'm getting the conflicted error message on my foreign key table, however, the drop-down menu populates the course category ID, an INT field as a number but the column is bound on InputText, as a string instead of InputNumber, although io tried using the InputNumber data type on the razor page, it didn't work. Looks like the numbers are being converted into string, hence the error or is there anything that I'm doing wrong here? I was able to enter the fields manually without the drop down menu and it works, this why i think the number is being converted to string.

Error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Course_CourseCategory". The conflict occurred in database "ITMS", table "dbo.CourseCategory", column 'CourseCategoryID'

[image][image]

Razor page

```
 <div class="col-12 row">
     <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Course Title:</label>
     <InputSelect @bind-Value="@newPerson.Course">
         <option value="0">Select</option>

         @foreach (var item in CourseCategories)
         {
            <option value="@item.CourseCategoryID">@item.Title</option>
         }
     </InputSelect>
     &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newPerson.Course)" />
</div>

<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Course Category ID:</label>
    <InputText id="CourseCategoryID" @bind-Value="newPerson.Course" placeholder="CourseCategoryID" />
    &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newPerson.CourseCategoryID)" />
</div>
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorDemoUI.Models
{
    public class DisplaySchoolModel
    {
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SchoolID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SchoolAdminPersonID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseCategory]
(
    [CourseCategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Summary] [ntext] NULL,
    [Description] [ntext] NULL,
    [Notes] [ntext] NULL,
    [Duration] [smallint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CourseCategory] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CourseCategoryID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Course]
(
    [CourseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CourseCategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SchoolID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Course] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [Duration] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Seats] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [ntext] NULL,
    [PublicClass] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SeatsAvailable] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Instructor] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsCancelled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ReasonForChange] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [HasPrerequisite] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PrerequisiteName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Course] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CourseID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Course] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_CourseCategory]     
        FOREIGN KEY([CourseCategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CourseCategory] ([CourseCategoryID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Course] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_CourseCategory]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Course] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_School]  
        FOREIGN KEY([SchoolID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[School] ([SchoolID])
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Course] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Course_School]
GO
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Way too mucch code and pictures, and still the most relevant parts (OnModelCreating ?) are missing. So are the tags. This is not about Blazor or Razor but about EntityFramework (I guess).

Answer (score 2):

`InputSelect` does not support binding to an integer:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputSelect.cs

Use `<select>` tag instead of `InputSelect` like

```
<select @bind="model.ByCountryId">
    @if (model?.Countries != null)
    {
        @foreach (var cnt in model.Countries)
        {
            <option value="@cnt.Id">@cnt.Name</option>
        }
    }
```